# Pegar dados da linha com checkbox marcado

Tags: php, html

Tenho o código abaixo e quero que o `array` `nome` contenha apenas os nomes das linhas que possuem o `checkbox` `cb` marcado.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" id="cb1" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nome[]" id="nome1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" id="cb2" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nome[]" id="nome2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" id="cb3" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nome[]" id="nome3"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="enviar">
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        var_dump($_POST['cb']);
        var_dump($_POST['nome']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

A forma mais simples de interagir num array seria usando [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php), mas no seu caso, seria melhor usar um `for` pois ao encontrar um item "checado", pegamos o valor nome com o mesmo índice.

Seria algo assim:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['cb']); $i++) {
   // verifica se está checado
   if(isset($_POST[$i]['cb']))  {
      // pega o nome de uma linha checada
      $nome = $_POST[$i]['nome']

      // aqui faz alguma coisa, como inserir ou atualizar no banco
   }
}
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma e não funcionou. Ficou assim o código:

$nome = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['cb']); $i++) {
        if(isset($_POST['cb'][$i]))  {
            $nome[] = $_POST['nome'][$i];
        }
    }
    var_dump($nome);

Answer (score -2):

Forma correta de utilização, testei aqui e está funcionando perfeitamente

```php
    $total = count($_POST['cb'];    

    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
       // verifica se está checado
       if(isset($_POST['cb'][$i]))  {
          // pega o nome de uma linha checada
          $nome = $_POST['nome'][$i];

          // aqui da seu insert ou update
       }
    }
```